# Please suggest a way to download file in new tab for chrome ios with angular

Tags: java, ios, angularjs, google-chrome

1. target="_blank" not working,
2. window.open(url,'_blank'); not working
3. < a href="link" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;"> not working

In every case a new tab is opened with 'about:blank' url and it never stops loading.

Answer (score -1):

Did this and it worked . Can't remember the source.

```
        var tabWindowId = $window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
        $timeout(function () { // async
            tabWindowId.location.href = 'myurl';
        }, 1001);
```